# Sending parameters in a linked route from datatables in Slim 3

Tags: datatable, twig, slim

I am using datatables for a table in Slim 3 and am trying to link to another page. I can do a link using path_for and "hard code" the variable I want to send, but don't know how to send a variable from datatables.

This is the old code i was using

```
return '<a href=edit.php?trnum=' + full.trnum + '>Edit or Review</a>';
```

And this is the slim code I'm using inside twig

```
return '<a href={{ path_for('edit', {'trannum' :  123}) }}>Edit or Review</a>';
```

I need to replace the '123' with full.trnum. Everything I try sends the literal string. How do I escape the {{ }} in order to send this variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats not that easy and beautiful to archieve, because the `{{ }}` stuff will get parsed by twig, which is on serverside and the `full.trnum` is (as far as I see) JavaScript, therefore gets executed on clientside.

You could set a placeholder in the `path_for`-method and then later replace this with the actual value.

Similar to this:

```
var urlWithPlaceholder = '{{ path_for('edit', {trannum: '%trannum%'}) }}';
var url = urlWithPlaceholder.replace('%trannum%', full.trnum);

return '<a href="' + url + '">Edit or Review</a>';
```

Comment: That works fine. I know there's an escape when use Vue.js with twig. But didn't know if it would work for this. Thanks tho.